# Como criar um vetor sem determinar seu tamanho em Java?

Tags: java, array

Tenho uma classe `TesteAplicacao` que é para testar e um a classe `Teste` com atributos e métodos.

Ao criar um vetor em Java:

```
Teste[] t = new Teste[10];// veja que teve definir um tamanho
```

Teria como criar vetor sem tamanho definido igual em C?

Comment: Qual vetor em C não tem o tamanho definido?

Comment: @utluiz provavelmente ele está falando dos *array* definido em tempo de execução disponível no C99. Ou pode estar falando de ponteiros acessados como se fossem *arrays*, menos provável. De qualquer forma, é claro que sempre há um tamanho definido. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array O que no Java é possível fazer direto.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simples, use um [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). O *array* do Java só pode ter tamanho fixo. Existem outras opções, mas quase sempre essa é a melhor.

Usaria mais ou menos assim:

```
ArrayList<Teste> t = new ArrayList<>(10);
t.add(new Teste());
t.get(0).nome = nome1;
System.out.println(t.get(0).nome);
t.add(new Teste());
t.get(1).nome = nome1;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Array/SizeUndeterminated.java).

Iniciei a capacidade da lista com 10, mas poderia iniciar com qualquer tamanho. Isto não quer dizer que já terá 10 elementos na lista, apenas que ela já reservou esse tamanho na memória. 10 é o tamanho padrão na implementação atual, então nesse caso específico até não precisaria colocar. É bom usar um tamanho que acha que vai precisar para evitar realocações.

Só lembrando que isso permite ter uma coleção de dados que pode variar de tamanho em tempo de execução sem maiores preocupações, mas o Java permite facilmente definir um *array* normal sem tamanho determinado em tempo de compilação, igual ao C. O que não pode é ter seu tamanho trocado depois de criado, igual ao C.

Na verdade não existe dado em computação que não tenha seu tamanho determinado em algum momento, o que dá para fazer é determiná-lo o mais tarde possível (sua criação) e poder mudar o tamanho (costuma exigir realocação na maioria dos casos).

O `ArrayList` é apenas uma estrutura que gerencia as realocações para você.

Comment: Na arrayList como que faço para usar assim `t[0].valor = i; t[0].nome = nome1; t[1].valor = i; t[1].nome = nome1;..........`

Comment: @bigown Sim, a capacidade inicial é 10 -> [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList--)

Answer (score 7):

Se você precisa de uma lista, sem tamanho definido, use `Java.util.ArrayList` ou `LinkedList`.

No Java não é possível criar um array com tamanho flexível.

Comment: Na arrayList como que faço para usar assim `t[0].valor = i; t[0].nome = nome1; t[1].valor = i; t[1].nome = nome1;..........`

Comment: com isso você quer adicionar um novo valor (add) ou alterar um valor existente (set)?

Answer (score 5):

Não exatamente, o tamanho de arrays deve ser definido em algum ponto e você não pode alterar ele após isso. Uma alternativa seria apenas declarar seu array `Teste[] t;` e definir o tamanho em algum ponto posterior com algo como `t = new Teste[size]`, contudo você ainda fica preso a necessidade de eventualmente determinar o tamanho. Outra, mais flexível, seria utilizar implementações da interface [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html), por exemplo [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) que é essencialmente uma classe que abstrai um vetor e pode possuir tamanho variável.

Exemplo de uso:

```
// instancia o objeto ArrayList
ArrayList<Teste> list = new ArrayList<Teste>();
// adiciona um item
list.add(new Teste());
// adiciona outro item
list.add(new Teste());
// etc, veja a doc de arraylist para os outros métodos.
```

Answer (score 5):

Não é possível criar um vetor com tamanho variável. O que é possível fazer é variar dinamicamente o tamanho do vetor que é criado, como no C99.

## Criando array variando o tamanho

Exemplo:

```
Test[] create(int size) {
    return new Test[size];
}
```

O código acima cria um novo vetor da classe `Test` com o tamanho passado por parâmetro. Logo você pode criar esse vetor do tamanho que precisar:

```
    Test[] array1 = create(10);
    Test[] array2 = create(20);
    Test[] array3 = create(lerEntradaDoUsuario());
```

## Clonando o array com novo tamanho

Embora o Java não tenha suporte a redimensionar arrays, por questões de eficiência no uso de memória, a solução básica se você precisa aumentá-lo é fazer uma cópia do array atual num novo array com o tamanho desejado.

Isso é muito simples usando a classe `Arrays` do Java:

```
//cria o array inicial
Test[] array = new Test[10];

//coloca um elemento na primeira posição
array[0] = new Test();
array[0].nome = "Eu";

//imprime o tamanho atual do array
System.out.println(array.length);

//clona o array atual em um novo array com 20 posições
//atribuindo na mesma variável
array = Arrays.copyOf(array, 20);

//imprime o tamanho do novo array
System.out.println(array.length);

//imprime o valor do elemento para provar que ele ainda está lá
System.out.println(array[0].nome);
```

## `ArrayList`

O exemplo anterior é interessante, mas é mais fácil usar uma implementação que já cuida devidamente disso.

Como já exemplificado em outras respostas, o `ArrayList` pode ser usado como uma estrutura de dados de tamanho variável.

Por debaixo dos panos, ele faz exatamente o que eu fiz no exemplo acima, isto é, ele tem um vetor interno que é redimensionado quando você adiciona mais elementos do que ele suporta num dado momento.

Answer (score 1):

Um vetor precisa de um tamanho fixo, se você precisar de um vetor dinâmico pode instanciar um arrayList e usar a função toArray para transformar o array em vetor.
 `List<Object> lista = new ArrayList<>();
lista.add("objeto1");
lista.add("objeto2");
Object[] vetor = lista.toArray();`